# Need to generalize jquery image preview

Tags: jquery, image, preview

I am allowing the user to see the uploaded image preview before it is saved to the database.
The HTML code is :

```
<div class="upload-preview">
  <img />
</div>
<input class="file" name="logo" type="file">
```

And my jquery code is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var preview = $(".upload-preview img");

$(".file").change(function(event){
   var input = $(event.currentTarget);
   var file = input[0].files[0];
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function(e){
       image_base64 = e.target.result;
       preview.attr("src", image_base64);
   };
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
});
```

The above code works great for one image.
What if I want to upload 10 images, I have to repeat the code 10 times.

I tried to generalize it but since the jquery code depends on the html class the image is uploaded to all the matching classes.

If I use an ID then I would have to repeat the jquery code for each ID.

Is there any way to generalize this problem so that it can preview multiple images with just one jquery function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you HTML code by this:

```
<div class="upload-preview" id="upload-preview">

</div>
<input class="file" name="logo" type="file"/>
```

And JS code by this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var preview = $("#upload-preview");

$(".file").change(function(event){
   var input = $(event.currentTarget);
   var file = input[0].files[0];
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function(e){
       image_base64 = e.target.result;
       preview.append("<img src='"+image_base64+"'/><br/>");
   };
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
});
}
```

Comment: In your answer where is the upload button in the html ? And if I remove the empty image tag, how would the image be previewed ? I think <img /> is necessary

Comment: @Ajey I have just modify your div code add the file upload after the div. and jquery will work. try this first.

Comment: Thx a lot for your efforts. I have almost got what I was looking for. But one last question. When I append the image I want them to append them horizontally . As of now they are getting appended vertically. Any idea how this can be achieved ?

Comment: @Ajey use this `preview.append("<img src='"+image_base64+"'/><br/>");` replace this line in the code.

Comment: Did that , but no change at all. Gotta figure out some other way. Please post here if you find the answer

Comment: heart : still the same error , please could you create a fiddle for that ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39922/discussion-between-ajey-and-broken-heart-)

Comment: @heart broken : the images are getting stacked vertically because you have used <br> but I need them horizontal, I mean in the same row.

Comment: @Ajey Then remove the `<br/>` and then check these images are comming horizontally. adn also you need to use the css to do it properly.

Comment: @Ajey My pleasure to help you.